# Can I be redirected to another route after a while in a Next.js server component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

Can I do something like the following in an `async` server component: after `ui` is rendered, wait 3 seconds and redirect to another route?

By analogy, how it done in a client component:

```
useEffect(() => {
  function delay(ms: number): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    });
  }
  delay(3000);
  router.push('/');
}, []);
```

But can I get the same result in the `app` route's server component?

Comment: You would basically keep the connection to the client open (will look like a blank page with spinner at the top) and then close it by redirecting the client.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
    
    // Your server component
    const MyServerComponent = async () => {
      const router = useRouter();
    
    // Render the UI
    
    // Wait 3 seconds.
      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));
    
      // Redirect to another route.
      router.push('/');
return <></>;
    }
    export default MyServerComponent;
```

first render the UI of the server component. Then, wait 3 seconds using the **Promise.resolve()** function. it will redirect to the **/** route using the **router.push()** function.

Comment: `useRouter()` hook imported from `next/router` is for **pages** router - OP mentioned **app** router - and `useRouter()` hook imported from `next/navigation` is for client component.